# Compressing Voice with MP3

Tags: compression, mp3, lame

I'm looking to compress some lectures which are in MP3 format. Currently, they're each about 75MB and I'm looking to compress them a lot. Can anyone suggest some good encoding options for LAME to get decent quality and small filesize?

I think the files are in stereo, but obviously they could be bounced down to mono if need be. Is there a guide for compressing just voice in MP3 efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://macintoshhowto.com/audio/how-to-compress-speech.html has this:

> 1. SMALLEST FILE SIZE ACCEPTABLE QUALITY. For very small file size (4MB
>    for 20 minutes) and acceptable
>    quality, use the LAME encoder (the the
>    separate article on Itunes songs to
>    find out about the LAME encoder) with
>    the following arguments in the
>    ‘Encoding options’ Box:
>
>    ```
>    -V 9 --vbr-new -mm -h -q 0
>    ```
> 2. An even better option than above but slightly more complicated is:
>    Firstly convert the file to 22khz
>    sample rate and mono, (eg in Audacity)
>    then use the following LAME settings:
>
>    ```
>    -V 8 --vbr-new -h -q 0
>    ```
> 3. BETTER QUALITY AND ACCEPTABLE FILE SIZE. For about twice the size files
>    (8MB for 20 minutes of speech) but
>    very very good quality try this in
>    LAME encoder:
>
>    ```
>    --preset voice
>    ```
>
> OR
>
> ```
> -V 8 --vbr-new -h -q 0
> ```

Comment: And, if you are not stuck on MP3, Windows Media Audio 9 Voice codec will get you good quality with excellent compression.